# Convert MySQL code to Access SQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2013

I am in need of some help as I am very new to Access.

I am trying to build a golf handicap database and to calculate the handicaps I have to pull the last rounds played for each golfer.

I have found the following code that would appear to do what I am after but it was written for MySQL not Access 2013.( I have changed the fields and table to match the table I will be using)

```
set @num := 0, @id := 0;

select PlayerID, RoundID, DatePlayed
from (
   select PlayerID, RoundID, DatePlayed,
      @num := if(@id = PlayerID, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @type := type as dummy
  from IncludedRounds
  order by PlayerID, DatePlayed
) as x where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have had a steep learning curve with Access and VBA snd I'm about halfway to my goal.

Comment: How are you running the Access SQL? Is this a stored query/view in the `.accdb` file, or a SQL string stored in a VBA function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it (*to get two last rounds for each player*)

```
SELECT PlayerID, RoundID, DatePlayed
  FROM IncludedRounds t
 WHERE DatePlayed IN
(
  SELECT TOP 2 DatePlayed 
    FROM IncludedRounds
   WHERE PlayerID = t.PlayerID 
   ORDER BY DatePlayed DESC, RoundID DESC
)
 ORDER BY PlayerID, DatePlayed DESC, RoundID DESC;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b816f/1)** demo *It's for SQL Server, but it should work in MS Access just fine*

Comment: Just tried it amending the 2 to 20 and it worked great thanks again.